# What should a Jew do at a funeral with an open casket?

Tags: funeral-burial-levaya

If a Jew is invited to a non-Jewish funeral at which there will be an open coffin with a body inside, should a Jew not attend the funeral? Should he avoid looking at the corpse inside the coffin? (all assuming the deceased is not Jewish)

Comment: I know you specifically asked about funerals. But, if I understand, correctly, in Israel, the body is buried openly (not in a casket) however, it is shrouded. I'm not sure at what point they make the *hesped*. But, wouldn't your question here be similar to this scenario?

Comment: I don't understand the point of the question. The only problem linked to any kind of contact with a deceased person regards cohanim only, not non cohanim Jews. The fact that the coffin is opened or closed is not necessary relevant

Comment: @kouty I ask because since at Jewish funerals, its prohibited to have an open coffin, be it a funeral for a kohen or non-Kohen, I wondered if the same reasoning of prohibiting that applies to non-Jewish funerals for Jewish attendees at a gentile funeral

Comment: @avig please please never put edit material in comments. Put it into the question so everyone can see it! If one person needed clarifications, probably many other silent readers do too. Please also include how you know an opened casket is prohibited at a Jewish funeral

Comment: relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45323/closed-caskets-for-jewish-burials and https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3218995/jewish/Why-Dont-Jews-Have-Open-Casket-Funerals.htm